# Magit: Auto-refresh "magit-status"

Tags: magit

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Magit

I want auto refresh buffer "**magit-status**" when was some change on files in my project.
So I set variable `magit-refresh-status-buffer` to `on non nil`. But it not help.

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't have to set `magit-refresh-status-buffer` to a non-nil value because the default value already is `t`. (Magit only refreshes after Emacs changed a file (i.e. on `save-buffer`) and after it ran `git` for side-effects.)

It sounds like you want the status buffer to be automatically refreshed when something *outside of Emacs* changes a file. Magit's refresh machinery does not support that - you will have to explicitly refresh using <kbd>g</kbd>.

It would theoretically be possible to watch for changes and then automatically refresh the status buffer, but that would affect performance and could lead to race conditions. There actually exists a package that implements this, [`magit-filenotify`](https://github.com/ruediger/magit-filenotify), but I recommend against using it because it has the issues mentioned earlier and also because it wasn't updated in two years.

---

To automatically refresh the status buffer whenever you visit a file-visiting buffer use:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'magit-after-save-refresh-status t)
```

Comment: Edit file outside Emacs - autorefresh not work. Edit file in Emacs - autorefresh again NOT work.

Comment: For most people it works. Need more information. But before that, try without your configuration, using `magit-emacs-Q-command` https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Debugging-Tools.html.

Comment: In minibuffer start command: `M-x magit-emacs-Q-command`.  As result in minibuffer: _Uncustomized Magit command saved to kill-ring, please run it in a terminal_.

Comment: That's what is supposed to happen. Now follow the instructions which you can find at the url I posted above.

Comment: OK. Maybe is it possible the next: When swith to buffer *magit-status* to emulate press "g" and as result in this buffer will be always actual info?

Comment: See my edited answer.