# Auto-refresh magit status only when magit is running

Tags: init-file, magit, hooks

I've seen the post [Magit: Auto-refresh “magit-status”](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36002/magit-auto-refresh-magit-status), and tarsius recommends the same method from the [Magit manual](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Automatic-Refreshing-of-Magit-Buffers.html) to set `magit-after-save-refresh-status` to non-nil to the `after-save-hook`:

`(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'magit-after-save-refresh-status t)`

This is a great solution when a Magit buffer is available. However, if this setting causes some noisy warnings when saving a file when a Magit buffer is not available:

`run-hooks: Symbol’s function definition is void: magit-after-save-refresh-status`

How can I get around this such that this setting is active only when there is a Magit buffer available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't that no Magit buffer exists but rather that Magit has not even been loaded. The result is that `Symbol’s function definition is void: magit-after-save-refresh-status`.

So you have to delay adding this function to the hook until it actually exists, like so:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'magit-mode
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'magit-after-save-refresh-status t))
```

Comment: Thank you! @tarsius, I see you're a maintainer of magit – could the config snippet [here](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Automatic-Refreshing-of-Magit-Buffers.html) be amended to this?